# protecting and signing messages in WCF

Tags: wcf, wcf-security, x509certificate, digital-signature

I'm a new member in this fantastic website and this is my first question here ..
I wish I can find the solution..

I'm building a website and I need to secure the communications between clients and the server.

I should Use WCF in the implementation.

My project's requirements :

- use WCF
- binding: ws2007HttpBinding
- security: HTTPS
- client: Sign

I should use HTTPS for securing the communications and I should make the client sign the message (it's important).

I install certificates in both server and Client But I don't knoe how to make the clients sign the message.

I can't use message security in the wcf because I need HTTPS.  Anyone can help me to know what is the TransportWithMessageCredential do for signing and how to implement such a thing??

Here is part of the app.config of the server:

```
<bindings>
    <ws2007HttpBinding>
        <binding name="ServiceWS2007HttpBindingConfg">
            <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" negotiateServiceCredential="false" />
            </security>
        </binding>
    </ws2007HttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
    <service name="Service">
        <endpoint address="https://MAHER-PC/EBPP/Service.svc" binding="ws2007HttpBinding"
         bindingConfiguration="ServiceWS2007HttpBindingConfg" contract="IService" />
    </service>
</services>
```

thanks....

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you're planning to sign.

A good place to start would be to have a look at setting the ProtectionLevel for your service in the service contract.

Information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa347692.aspx

How to:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa347791.aspx